# Batch File : Renaming multiple files based on contents

Tags: batch-file

Let me start out by saying I have searched and found a few similar questions, but for the life of me I can not get it to work for my use.

I have a folder with several files with different names (File.Config) I need to rename them based on the 7th line of the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
<add key="StylesSheetFilename" Value=""/>
<add key=""/>
<add key="" />
<add key="" />
<add key="LineNumber" value="LName" />
<!--Com Port Properties-->
</appSettings>
```

I would like them renamed in this format File_LName.Config. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I have already spent several hours on what I thought would be a simple task.

Comment: operating system? hopefully linux. Are you looking for an answer in BASH?

Comment: Windows, Looking hopefully for a batch file.

Comment: @RockyR, I am all for obfuscating data, but at least put a real value in your example.

Comment: @zhqiat, hover your mouse over the tag and read the description.

Comment: @Squashman The keys that I removed should play no part in the solution since I would assume the lines are skipped.  If I am wrong I can add the data back in. The LineNumber value can be any alphanumeric string 9 characters or less.

Comment: @RockyR, because you had LineNumber for the key name and value, there was no way for me to ascertain which one you wanted.

Comment: @Squashman I must have changed that immediately after you replied I thought I had done it before. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is based exactly on how you have your config shown.  If the 7th line of all the config files are not formatted the same it will not work.  I would then suggest you to use VBscript or Jscript to solve this as it can natively read XML files.  Please test this on a couple of your files in a temporary folder.

```
 @echo off
 setlocal enableExtensions enableDelayedExpansion
 for /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /a-d /b *.config') do (
    < "%%~G" (
        for /L %%L in (1,1,7) do (
            set /P "line="
        )
    )
    REM FOR /F "tokens=5 delims== " %%H IN ("!line!") do rename "%%~G" "%%~nG_%%~H%%~xG"
    FOR /F tokens^=4^ delims^=^" %%H IN ("!line!") do rename "%%~G" "%%~nG_%%~H%%~xG"
 )

 endlocal
```